# If uasort callback returns 0, elements are reversed

Tags: php, sorting

If I usort an array and the callback returns 0, the elements are reversed.

```
<?php

$a = array("1", "2", "3");

print_r($a);

function nosort($a, $b){
    return 0;
}

uasort($a, "nosort");

print_r($a);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [0] => 1
)
```

Why does this happen? Wouldn't 0 not switching elements be a more sane default?

Comment: Using `1` will keep their position: https://eval.in/220979

Comment: It's more a question of why doesn't using 0 keep their position? That seems like it would be the sane default

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes more sense for the question. I always assumed `1` was increase element index, `0` keep the same, `-1` decrease element index. (+1 as interested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort):

> **Note**
>   If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.

You've defined all entries in the array as having equal comparisons so PHP can do whatever it feels like with them.  The fact that it came out in reverse order may just be coincidence.
You should not, *under any circumstances*, depend on this behavior as it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`uasort()` is *not* a stable sort - that is, there's no guarantee that two equal elements (those for which the comparison returns 0) will retain their order. They may, they may not. The fact that they happen to be reversed here isn't something you should count on, either.

The `uasort()` docs include [an example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#114535) of a stable variation on `uasort()`, if you need that.